# Order of this group?

Tags: abelian-groups, direct-product

It s a stupid question probably but i dont know. It was a little question in a test. The order ( cardinality) of $G= \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$. I think it s $12$, the direct product is the cartesian product of the two sets $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ with the same operation etc. But i think it s not the right answer (if it was $12$ why ask it, it s obvious...)

Comment: It is indeed $12$. As you said, the underlying set of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$ is the cartesian product of the underlying sets of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: Yes it's obvious if you know the definitions. Maybe your instructor wanted to give you a few points with an easy question. Maybe some people will be confused by the fact that $2$ divides $6$ so the resulting group isn't $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. The order of the Cartesian product of two groups is the product of the order of the groups. Good job!